# How can I bind a form to every view?

Tags: java, playframework

While I love the type safe forms in the Play framework, it can also have its drawbacks.

I got a web app where a form is placed into the side bar, which basically gets rendered in every possible view.

As you can imagine, this creates a lot of boilerplate code in every view.

1. declare in views
2. create the form in all corresponding controllers.

Is there a way to avoid that ?

What options do I have ?

- I could create a simple action ( **play.mvc.Action.Simple** ), to eventually put the form into the ctx().args, but I don't really like that solution.
- I could just declare the form in every view and every controller.
- I could just drop Play forms ( but I'd rather not )

Any other ideas?

Notes: Play for Java, V: 2.5.x

Comment: You can use a [DynamicForm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms#Handling-a-form-that-is-not-related-to-a-Model).

Comment: @marcospereira That's a good idea, thanks